# Como deixar a tela sempre acesa mesmo quando fechar o app

Tags: java, android

Estou desenvolvendo um *app* e estou querendo implementar um método que faça com que sua tela nunca apague.

Pesquisei algumas formas pela internet e consegui fazer isto dentro do aplicativo. Porém, gostaria que este recurso continuasse funcionando quando eu minimizasse o aplicativo, mantendo sempre o telefone com a tela ligada mesmo usando outras aplicações.

Meu objetivo é fazer algo tipo isto:  youtube.com/watch?v=ywXg3cqL8Tw

Pensei em usar um método assíncrono junto ao `WAKE_LOCK`, mas não consegui.

Vi pelos exemplos como o do *app* do link disponibilizado acima que para fazer funcionar com o *app* desligado, ele esta utilizando uma classe `extends Servise` que com isso ele consegue manter a tela acesa mesmo com o *app* desligado.

Abaixo vocês podem ver meu código, tentei pelo `onBind`, mas não consegui também:

```
public class ServiceScreen extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "Service";

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Notification n;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    // Change this int to some number specifically for this app
    int notifId = 5315;
    //Screen luz;

    IBinder b;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //getCurrentFocus().setKeepScreenOn(true);
        //int x = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
        arg0.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        return b;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        // Init the SharedPreferences and Editor

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        editor = prefs.edit();

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        String notifTitle = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        String notifMessage = context.getResources().getString(R.string.ligado);
        n = new Notification();
        n.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        n.tickerText = "Buffering";
        n.when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Intent nIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, nIntent, 0);

        n.setLatestEventInfo(context, notifTitle, notifMessage, pIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(notifId, n);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        String notifTitle = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        String notifMessage = context.getResources().getString(R.string.ligado);

        n.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        n.tickerText = notifMessage;
        n.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        n.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Intent nIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, nIntent, 0);
        n.setLatestEventInfo(context, notifTitle, notifMessage, pIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(notifId, n);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        notificationManager.cancel(notifId);
    }
}
```

Caso alguém saiba como me auxiliar a manter a tela acesa, toda dica é bem vinda!

Comment: Qual a api minima que você setou pra sua aplicacao?

Comment: É a padrão de quando tu cria um projeto, acredito que é a Froyo 2.2

Comment: Tenho um projeto aqui com o mesmo comando que você está utilizando e funciona normalmente. Porém, adicionei diretamente no `onCreate()`.

Comment: mas quando você minimiza a aplicação ele segue funcionando? Ou seja, se deixar na tela inicial do Android por exemplo, ela fica sempre ligada?

Comment: Se você sair da tela, é claro que não vai funcionar. Sugiro que dê uma lida em [ciclo de vida android](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html). [Aqui](http://www.devmedia.com.br/entendendo-o-ciclo-de-vida-de-uma-aplicacao-android/22922) tem uma boa explicaçao tambem.

Comment: Talvez fosse mais interessante você nos dizer o que quer fazer com isso. Talvez haja uma outra solução. Por exemplo, sua intenção é fazer com que alguma operação continue rodando?

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção galera, basicamente eu apenas quero ativar a tela para que fique sempre ligada
Sei que da pra fazer pelas configurações no próprio Android, mas queria fazer isto pelo app.
meu objetivo é poder minimizar o app e a tela do telefone ficar sempre ligada, e quando eu quiser desativar, eu volto no app e desativo

Comment: Pelo que vi, realmente não consigo devido ao ciclo de vida da atividade. Agradeço pela ajuda de todos. Mas caso possam me ajudar com outra dúvida rápida, ficaria muito grato. Sei que existe este recurso de deixar a tela do Android sempre ligada pelas configurações dele, teria como eu alterar estas informações permanentemente pelo app? Basicamente, eu queria fazer algo tipo isso: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywXg3cqL8Tw



     Abraço!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consegui fazer aqui!
desta forma posso desligar o *app* que ele segue mantendo a tela ligada.

Acrescentei na `onCreate` da classe `ServiceScreen` este código:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "watever");
wl.acquire();
```

Comment: Funcionou bem, mas para os Android a partir do 5.0, ele não funciona. Tem ideia do que possa ser?